# Available Methods to inspect Memory heap/usage?

Tags: node.js

I had written an Node.js application and have some huge memory usages, but not all the time.

It is possible to inspect an Node.js instance and its objects like Java and their VisualVM "inspector"?

I wan't to see, which variables has huge data, for sample..

Comment: I am not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for but you can explore [heapdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heapdump). Once you have two heapsnapshots, you can compare the difference between the memory usage in [chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling)